# How do I fetch the number of users in a discord server and display it in the title of a voice channel?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want to count how many users are online on my server and display it in a Discord voice channel.

Is it possible to display the record of online users and "track" their presence every minute?

Comment: What do mean by "display it on a vocal channel"? Also, you should first [try doing it by yourself](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)

Comment: Displaying a certain nomber like total users in the guild actually works with `client.channels.get(serverStats.botCountID).setName(`Bots : ${member.guild.members.filter(m => m.user.bot).size}`);`

Answer (score 0):

You can add the code in the ready event to an existing ready event or otherwise, you can just add this into your code.

```js
/**
* Updates a voice channel with a member count every minute
* @param {Discord.Client} client
*/

client.on("ready", async() => {
  const guildID = ""; // Place the server id here
  const channelID = ""; // Create a voice channel in the server
  await bot.guilds.cache.get(guildID)?.members.fetch(); // Fetch server members on start so the cache is correct

  const guild = bot.guilds.cache.get(guild);
  guild.channels.cache.get(channelID).edit({
    name: `${guild.members.cache.size}`
  });
  setInteval(()=>{
    guild.channels.cache.get(channelID).edit({
      name: `${guild.members.cache.size}`
    });
  }, 60_000); // 60 seconds interval
});
```

An explanation of the code above:
guildID is the id of a server, please place that in the "". the channelID is the id of the voice channel that you have created. The fetching part fetches the servers member count to ensure that the member count is accurate and correct. The guild constant is then fetching the guild. There is an interval(occurs every 60, theres also a channel edit function outside of the interval as the interval starts only until 60 seconds after the bot starts so that being outside automatically changes the channel name on start). The interval loops every 60 seconds and renames the channel to the member count.